# Como passar dados de arquivo CSV para um array no Java?

Tags: java, array, arquivo, csv

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Eu tenho um arquivo .CSV com diversos números em duas colunas (1032,54832). Eu preciso pegar esses números e passá-los para um vetor. Como faço isso?

Eu fiz um código para importar o arquivo e consigo exibir os números, mas na hora de passar os valores para o vetor, estou tendo problemas. Abaixo segue o que eu fiz (Esse código está dentro de um botão que exibe os números dentro do arquivo .CSV):

```
            String LineFile = new String ();

            File fileCSV = new File(LocalFile.getText());

            try 

            {
                Scanner reader = new Scanner(fileCSV);

                while (reader.hasNext())

                {

                    LineFile = reader.nextLine();


                   String numb[] = LineFile.split(",");
                    System.out.println(LineFile);

                }   



            } 



            catch (FileNotFoundException e)

            {

            }
```

Comment: Voce ja nao fez essa pergunta? Apagou e recriou?

Comment: Sim. Reformulei a questão e apaguei o post anterior.

Comment: Recomendo que evite fazer isso, pois o sistema computa pergunta excluida negativamente para o teu perfil, podendo resultar em proibicoes de criar novos posts no site. SEMPRE opte por editar e melhorar o mesmo post.

Comment: Você está a obter o array dado pelo `split` mas não faz nada com ele. Falta adicionar a um array. E se estiver com algum tipo de erro então falta incluir o erro na pergunta, para que seja claro qual o problema com que está a lidar

Comment: Agradeço o alerta. A política do sistema do Stack OverFlow é horrível nessas questões.

Comment: E outra, voce nao explica q problemas está tendo, sua pergunta nao está muito clara, alem do codigo nem ser reproduzivel. Sugiro que edite e explique melhor em que ponto esta tendo dificuldades, pois com um pedaço de codigo q nem sequer é possivel executar, fica dificil ajudar sem entender o problema

Comment: Como não explico? O problema que estou tendo é passar os valores para um array. Se o código não estivesse funcionando, então minha dúvida seria sobre o não funcionamento do código. E no meu eclipse está funcionando normalmente.

Comment: Entao forneça um codigo que seja um **[mcve]**, assim  e possivel testar e verificar o problema

Comment: É um exemplo mínimo. É o script que eu fiz pra percorrer o arquivo CSV.

Comment: Não é um exemplo minimo, completo e verificavel, se eu colar isso e executar, nada irá acontecer. Recomendo que leia o link, nao adianta ficar resistente e nao fornecer o que é pedido, quem se prejudica nao obtendo ajuda é voce mesmo. Quem vem nos comentarios é porque quer te ajudar, mas se vc nao está disposto a fornecer conforme solicitado, voce dificulta e atrasa mais ainda uma solucao.

Comment: Você diz na pergunta que está tendo problemas. Qual problema exatamente?

Comment: Stateless Dev Estou tendo dificuldades em passar os valores do arquivo para o array (ou para o arrayList, no caso).

Answer (score 1):

Vou oferecer uma alternativa mais funcional e mais limpa:

```
List<String> numb = Files.lines(Paths.get(new File(LocalFile.getText())).toURI()), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
                        .flatMap(Pattern.compile(",")::splitAsStream)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

O método [lines()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.charset.Charset-) lê todas as linhas de um arquivo e retorna um `Stream` de `String`, que, a seguir, é splitado e retornado como uma `List` de `String`.

Obs: essa solução assume que seu método `LocalFile.getText()` esteja retornando um caminho válido de um arquivo.

Comment: Vou testar. Obrigado. :)
Uma dúvida: eu coloco dentro do while?

Comment: Não. Toda essa lógica do `Scanner` é feita internamente pelo método `lines()`. Deixe apenas o _try/catch_, acrescentando um _catch_ para `IOException` também.

Comment: Olá. Eu coloquei o script no meu eclipse. No entanto apareceu o seguinte erro:

         "Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error, insert "}" to complete MethodBody
 - Line breakpoint:MethodsOrdering [line: 139] - 
  actionPerformed(ActionEvent)
 - Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody
 - Syntax error, insert ";" to complete LocalVariableDeclarationStatement
 - The method get(URI) in the type Paths is not applicable for the 
  arguments (File)
 - Syntax error, insert "Finally" to complete TryStatement
 - Syntax error, insert "}" to complete Block"

Comment: São erros relativos a você ter `{` ou `}` a mais ou a menos no seu código. Revise seu código e tenha certeza que cada bloco é aberto e fechado corretamente.

Comment: Na parte do "StandardCharsets" ele dá esse erro junto com o erro da linha:

"Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody".

Eu tenho que criar essa ClassBody?

Comment: Não. Como eu falei, está faltando chaves no seu código. Reveja se cada `{` tem seu respectivo `}`.

Comment: As chaves estão fechadas corretamente. O problema aparece quando eu insiro seu script.

Comment: Colega, eu coloquei o código assim e funcionou:

"ArrayList<String> numb = (ArrayList<String>) Files.lines(Paths.get(LocalFile.getText()))
           .flatMap(Pattern.compile(",")::splitAsStream)
           .collect(Collectors.toList());"

Tem algo de errado com o código?

Comment: Deveria funcionar da maneira que postei, mas se pra você funcionou desta forma, ótimo.

Answer (score 1):

Se a sua necessidade é criar um vetor com as linhas do arquivos, você necessita antes obter a quantidade de linhas do arquivo. Isso irá te forçar a ler o arquivo 2 vezes: 1) Para pegar a quantidade de linhas; 2) Ler o conteúdo do arquivo. Uma sugestão que dou é utilizar coleções ao invés de vetor, pois será necessário apenas uma operação de I/O. Nesse caso, o seu código ficaria dessa maneira:

```
public class CSVReader {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File csvFile = new File(LocalFile.getText());
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(csvFile);
    while(scanner.hasNext()) {
        String[] line = scanner.nextLine().split(",");
        String col1 = line[0];
        String col2 = line[1];
        System.out.println(col1);
        System.out.println(col2);
     }
   }
}
```

Caso esteja familiarizado com as expressões lambdas do Java 8, pode seguir a solução do @StatelessDev, alterando o caractere do split de ";" para ",".

Comment: Obrigado por chamar a atenção para o ";", Claudivan. Alterei na minha resposta.

Comment: Certo. Mas esse código seria somente para exibir os números do arquivo, correto?

Comment: Para o código dele funcionar como você precisa, você deve, fora do `while`, criar uma lista de `String` e, dentro do `while`, adicionar nessa lista as variáveis `col1` e `col2`.

Comment: Isso mesmo @StatelessDev. Ficaria dessa forma:

`List<LineFile> lines = new ArrayList<LineFile>();
 while(scanner.hasNext()) {
  String[] line = scanner.nextLine().split(",");
  LineFile lf = new LineFile();
  lf.setCol1(line[0]);
  lf.setCol2(line[1]);
  lines.add(lf);
 }`

Comment: @ClaudivanMoreira Essa parte do "LineFile lf = new LineFile();" dá o seguinte erro:

         "Multiple markers at this line
 - Line breakpoint:MethodsOrdering [line: 174] - 
  actionPerformed(ActionEvent)
 - LineFile cannot be resolved to a type
 - LineFile cannot be resolved to a type"

Comment: @ClaudivanMoreira Você sabe porque ocorre esse erro? No meu eclipse é como se o LineFile não existisse. Ele sugere que seja colocado apenas "Line", ou "Line2D".

Comment: @GabrielAugusto posta o stacktrace do erro que fica melhor do pessoal te ajudar. A princípio, parece-me que o import da sua classe não está sendo resolvido. Remove e adiciona ele novamente. As vezes o eclipse buga e fica lançando uns erros não muito claros.